# How to change number inside of div class and update it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the existing HTML code on a site. See the example below:

```js
var multiplier = 1.5;
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0
})
        
//for first two occurences
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
for (var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++) {
    var price = priceEls[i].innerText;
    var priceN = getNumber(price)*multiplier;
    alert("Price: " + formatter.format(priceN));
}
//for last occurence
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName("column--container value-item");
for (var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++) {
    var price = priceEls[i].innerText;
    //alert("Price: " + price);
    var priceN = getNumber(price)*multiplier;
    alert("Price: " + formatter.format(priceN));
}
        
function getNumber(myString) {
    var numb = myString.match(/\d/g);
    numb = numb.join("");
    //alert (numb);
    return(parseInt(numb));
}
```

```html
<div class="price">$2,000</div>
<div class="price">
    <span>$</span>
    3,000
</div>
<div class="column--container value-item">
    <span class="text-semibold-xs">Price</span>
    $1,500                  
</div>
```

How do I update the HTML code with those new values?

Comment: for updating an element's inner element, you can use `someElement.innerHTML = "some_value"` or `someElement.innerText =  "some_value"`. is that what you want?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61r8wfy2/2/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do after calculating the new prices is set the `innerText` of an element with the text you are using on the alert. So one of your loops can look like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < priceEls.length; i++) {
  var price = priceEls[i].innerText;
  var priceN = getNumber(price)*multiplier;
  priceEls[i].innerText = "Price: " + formatter.format(priceN);
}
```

I would recomend using `forEach` for looping instead of `for`.